# What is the best method of data retrieval from sharepoint and processing it, by using Java?

Tags: java, api, rest, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint site, from which I'm periodically trying to retrieve  all the documents/sub-folders under a parent folder and then process it using java application. I think there are couple option here when it comes to connecting and retrieving the data...1). connecting to sharepoint using it's API (may be using a token based auth) 2). folder/files downloading to local disk drive prior to processing the data....  3) connecting to sharepoint database and get the data (I don't think it is a preferred option) . Can someone suggest which of these options is better and why?  Any resources pointing to the solution would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, I would suggest you use SharePoint api to access SharePoint.

Access SharePoint database directly is not suggested.

Two threads would be helpful for you.

https://vectus.wordpress.com/2014/07/22/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-windows-authentication-java-application-defaulthttpclient-ntcredentials/

https://github.com/quantr-research/Sharepoint-Java-API

Answer (score 0):

I found that the easiest way is to use the sharepoint rest api and wrap the requests/responses in JSONObjects. I have develop a working library (not fully covering all sharepoint rest api functionalities but still working on it) that will save you a lot of time doing this and also provide you a starting point to extend functionalities of the API. You can take a look of it here

https://github.com/kikovalle/PLGSharepointRestAPI-java